# Console opens then immediately closes, but code checkst out (Python, Sublime)

Tags: python

Hi I'm relatively new to coding and I don't know why this code isn't working

```
gender = input("What is your gender(m/f)?")
if gender.upper() == M:
    throw = paper
elif gender.upper() == F:
    throw = rock
else:
    print("issue")
print throw
```

Comment: `print throw`: probably running python 3. Try parentheses around this else syntax error.

Comment: also "m" instead of M...

Comment: If you're running on windows, don't double click your file to run. Invoke through the terminal.

Comment: Why is everyone pointing out errors in the code? The real problem here is that the OP can't debug their own program. If you fix the errors but don't explain how to run a program in a way that shows the exception traceback, what good does that do? Do you want the OP to come back to post another SO question every time their code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which editor/runtime are you using? You should be able to configure keeping the console open when your program exits so you can see any errors.

In your specific case it looks like you're using Python 3, and you need to surround the `print` argument with parentheses here too:

```
print(throw)
```

As well as using quotes around `"M"` and `"F"` to signify that they're strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
gender = input("What is your gender(m/f)?")
if gender.upper() == "M":
    throw = "paper"
elif gender.upper() == "F":
    throw = "rock"
else:
    print("issue")
    exit() # terminate here , because name 'throw' is not defined.
print (throw)
```